Is it possible to resolve path must not include query string warning here
I'm very new to working with swagger and trying to document one of our Restapi endpoint. We have an endpoint where I'm looking to customize response based on the input parameter, however getting warnings as "path must not include query string" in both lines. Not able to figure out on what is incorrect in the below specs and any inputs are really helpful.
/Employees?EmpNbr={EmpNbr}?DateofJoin={DateofJoin}:
/Employees?EmpNbr={EmpNbr}?DateofJoin={DateofJoin}?format={format}:
I even tried to update it to below with no luck
/Employees?EmpNbr={EmpNbr}&DateofJoin={DateofJoin}:
/Employees?EmpNbr={EmpNbr}&DateofJoin={DateofJoin}&format={format}:
Below is my struct

type EmployeeWithRoot struct {
    Employees []Employees `json:"Employee"`
}
type Employees struct {
    EmpNbr     sql.NullString  `json:"EmpNbr"`
    DateofJoin      sql.NullString   `json:"DateofJoin"`
        DeptId  sql.NullString  `json:"DeptId"`
        DeptName sql.NullString  `json:"DeptName"`
}

paths:
  /Employees?EmpNbr={EmpNbr}?DateofJoin={DateofJoin}:
    get:
      description: Get Employee info 
      summary: Get Employee.
      tags:
      - Employees
      operationId: GetEmployees
      parameters:
      - name: EmpNbr
        in: path
        description: Employee ID(Example:0123456789)
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: DateofJoin
        in: path
        description: Input DateofJoin(Example:mmddyyyy(01012023))
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employees'
  /Employees?EmpNbr={EmpNbr}?DateofJoin={DateofJoin}?format={format}:
    get:
      description: Get Employees info as per additional condition 
      summary: Get EmployeeRoot Hdr.
      tags:
      - Employees
      operationId: GetEmployeeRootHdr
      parameters:
      - name: EmpNbr
        in: path
        description: Emp ID(Example:0123456789)
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: DateofJoin
        in: path
        description: Input DateofJoin(Example:mmddyyyy(01012023))
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: format
        in: path
        description: additional check
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
        allowEmptyValue: true      
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employeewithroot'
components:
  schemas:
    Employeewithroot:
      properties:
        Employee:
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employees'
          type: array
          x-go-name: Employees
      type: object
      x-go-package: pkg/model
    Employees:
      properties:
        EmpNbr:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        DateofJoin:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        DeptId:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        DeptName:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        x-go-package: pkg/model
    


Listed the steps above

Does this answer your question? How to define more than one response body schema in OpenAPI

Not really. I have to get different responses based on the parameter's and their corresponding model from a single endpoint. I'm not sure how can I define Oneof to perform this as.

I commented on the other issue that it's not possible to define the response based on conditional parameters.  I also commented the query parameters can not be defined in the pathItem object, they are defined in the parameters array and must use the in: query definition
